# Have you ever done 'anything' that you were completely sure was of your own free will? Is this a double relative clause?

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

> Have you ever done *anything* that you were completely sure was of
>   your own free will?

Might I trouble you to tell me whether my parsing is right or not?

It seems to be a double relative clause.

1. *anything* that you were completely sure
2. *anything* that was of your own free will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certainty of *completely sure* applies to *being of your own free will*, not to *done anything*.

This is asking if you've done something that was of your own free will, and that you are completely sure was of your own free will.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand 'something that was of your own free will'. But, I don't get why 'word-order' is like this: something that you are completely sure 'was' of your own free will.  Would you tell me 'was' is what? why is 'was' placed between 'sure' and 'of your own free will'?

Comment: *Was* is the simple past form of *to be*. It is the fact that it *was* of your own free will that the question asks if you were sure of. It refers to the past, in the sense of when you were doing that thing that may have been of your own free will.

Comment: If so, isn't this a double relative clause? In a relative clause, 'two verbs' seem to exist. anything [that you 'were' completely sure 'was' of your own free will]? Were you completely sure (that) anything (you did) was of your own free will?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "double relative clause", and a quick ferret around online hasn't been terribly revealing. I went with the definition you seemed to indicate - both acting to specify the object of the main clause. The thing is, that's not what they are doing. They are more... nested. It's not something that you were sure of, and that was of your own free will, it's something you were "sure was of your own free will".